# Does an invalid index take up space in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, compression

I am using basic compression in Oracle to archive seemingly unused tables as a first step to dropping them. I used these commands:

```
alter table table1 compress basic;
alter table table1  move;
```

The move invalidates the index. Does the invalid index still take up space? The index no longer shows up in a query of the *USER_SEGMENTS* table.

This would be useful to know whether I need to drop or rebuild and compress the index to save even more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE ... MOVE marks the indexes built on that table UNUSABLE.

In earlier versions, UNUSABLE indexes still had their segments and the allocated space was not freed up. Starting from version 11.2, UNUSABLE index segments are automatically removed.
A non-existent segment consumes less space than a compressed index segment :)
If you want to use those indexes again, you have to rebuild them. Otherwise, just drop them.

Comment: We are using 11.2. Thanks for the answer.